# Is there a way to return indices of one array which minimize the output of a function of multiple arrays without for loops?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the indices of an array which minimize a four-input function. Two of the function's inputs are the axes of the 2d array, which I have currently turned into two 1d arrays.
Currently, I am using two nested for loops to go through all relevant values of the functions first two inputs, x and y, and using numpy's np.argmin to return the index bringing the minimum value of the function with that specific x and y. Restructuring the function so that the for loops went through the values in the 2d array involves two more nested for loops, so I assume it would also take longer than the current method even if relying entirely on vector operations. Is there a way to get argmin to only look in the 2d array so I can make another, larger array provide all relevant x and y, or will I have to use np.fromfunction or np.where? Or would it be more effective to set it up to use multiprocessing?
My 4-input function is continuous for all values, differentiable for all points which matter, and its concavity is seemingly random.
I have also tried:

- making the nested for loops a function (using np.fromfunction and just running it as a regular python function), but I receive errors from trying to use vector operations then, because the width and height of the image are not guaranteed to be the same
- Making a 4d Array of all (calculated to be) relevant values of x and y and the manual 2d array which is two 1d arrays from the start, but this used way too much memory to be able to run it

Below is a simplified version of my entire code (with two random 1d arrays instead of two 1d arrays converted from a manually input 2d array)
If it is important, np.hypot is not the function I am using; I am using one which uses an iterative process until the result converges.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import math

AArray = np.random.rand(50)*3011
BArray = np.random.rand(50)*2009

width = 3011
height = 2009
num_cells = len(AArray)

image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
putpixel = image.putpixel
imgx, imgy = image.size

nr = (np.ceil(np.random.rand(num_cells)*256)).astype(int)
ng = (np.ceil(np.random.rand(num_cells)*256)).astype(int)
nb = (np.ceil(np.random.rand(num_cells)*256)).astype(int)

for y in range(imgy):
    for x in range(imgx):
        j = np.argmin(np.hypot(y-BArray,x-AArray))
        putpixel((x, y), (nr[j], ng[j], nb[j]))

image.show()
```

I want to know what can replace the nested for loops and have the same functionality, or if that is even possible since width and height are almost always going to be unequal.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example: a small example with inputs and desired output.

Comment: You can use scipy optimize package to find local minimum or maximum https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy.html#optimization-and-fit-scipy-optimize

Comment: You could replace the nested loop with a single loop using itertools.product: `for x,y in itertools.product(range(imgx),range(imgy)):`

Comment: Thank you rtrwalker and politinsa; I think using scipy for this loop and itertools for the actual function will be fastest.

Comment: The properties of your function matter a lot. Is it continuous, differentiable, convex ...? Can you rewrite it in pytorch to efficiently use gradient descent?